# joining jq arrays, for CSV output

Tags: csv, jq

I'm looking to create a CSV based on two json arrays (arrays are a reduction of a large jason array with key value pairs)

```
[
  "Name",
  "Role",
  "Type",
  "Service",
  "Group",
]
[
  "some-server.com",
  "web server",
  "production",
  "apps",
  "main",
]
```

I'm able to get a more less what I'm looking for with:

```
jq -r '[.Tags[].Key], [.Tags[].Value] | join (",")' output.json
```

The issue is, the keys are not always sorted in the same order. For some objects I get:

```
Name, Role, Type
```

and other times:

```
Role, Type Name ..
```

I'm looking for a way to make the output consistent.

Comment: Can you please provide a valid input JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can normalize the objects using:

```
def sortKeys: to_entries | sort | from_entries
```

For example, if A is an array of the unnormalized objects, you could write:

```
A | map(sortKeys)
```

Or the objects could be normalized as soon as they are created.

For CSV, you might want to fix the order based on a pre-determined array of key names.  In that case, you could use:

```
def selectKeys(keys):
  . as $in | reduce keys[] as $k ({}; . + {($k): $in[$k]})
```